# Cakephp URL rewriting

Tags: php, url, cakephp, url-rewriting

How do you make www.homepage.com/app/shoppingcart look like www.homepage.com/shoppingcart -

how to rewrite the URL-s

is there a url rewrite plugin for cakephp that does such things

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have installed your cakephp files correctly and app is a controller and shoppingcart is an action in the app controller.

```
Router::connect('/shoppingcart', array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'shoppingcart'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main .htaccess like below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```